# Where can I get a complete list of UTF-8 characters for the English language?

Tags: php, python, utf-8, character

I'm mainly interested in the English language characters and punctuation.

I need it for test data so I can emulate how an API handles different characters.

Can I generate it using Python or PHP?

Comment: English borrows words and phrases from other languages including their accents, foreign words may be embedded in English text, and there are many cases of units or proper names using characters that you might not otherwise expect (e.g. µ is both a unit prefix and in the name of µTorrent), to just name a few cases.  I'm not sure what you hope to gain by excluding these cases from your tests.

Comment: I hadn't actually thought about greek letters, latin accents etc - good shout!

Comment: I’ve run some corpus analytics on the very large PubMed Open Access collection, and you’d be astounded at the non‐ASCII Unicode code points used in those English‐language texts. The 7 most frequently occurring are `EN DASH`, `NO-BREAK SPACE`, `PLUS-MINUS SIGN`, `MINUS SIGN`, `EM SPACE`, `GREEK SMALL LETTER MU`, `GREEK SMALL LETTER BETA`, and `GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA` — in that order. There are a surprising number of code points from the “astral planes”, plus non‐Latin scripts that get nonce‐used for author names. But that is highly technical biomedical text of published scientific papers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most English characters are simply ascii, but [here](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) is a complete list of utf-8 characters.

[Here](http://csbruce.com/~csbruce/software/utf-8.html) is another list, sorted by sets of characters.

Comment: Is u"résumé" English?  It's in the dictionary.  But it sure looks French to my eye.

Comment: nice one - those two lists kind of make up for each other's deficiencies - thanks!

Comment: If you look at [the two tables on slides 4 and 5](http://training.perl.com/OSCON2011/gbu.html) showing the frequency of non‐ASCII code points in the PMC Open Access collection, you will see that English‐language scientific text uses a huge amount of Unicode, including not just letters but quite a bit of punctuation, symbols and “styling” spaces.

Answer (score 1):

There's a useful interactive table [here](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) broken down by language/usage

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the string module for python, that's got a few helpful data structures with data in them:

http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#